# Spring cloud stream binding kafka doesnt consume messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Hello everyone and thank you for your time. My problem is that I don't get any messages from kafka topics when I use spring cloud stream with kafka binding and I really don't understand why. Everything works fine with spring-kafka, but I want to try spring cloud stream. I'm using spring boot 3.1.4, so for spring cloud I'm taking the latest version. I tried to do everything according to the spring documentation, but it seems I missed something

```
implementation ('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:4.0.4')
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
spring.cloud.function.definition=ordersConsumer;productsConsumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.ordersConsumer-in-0.destination=data.order
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.productsConsumer-in-0.destination=data.product
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.ordersConsumer-in-0.group=my-group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.productsConsume-in-0.group=my-group
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.ordersConsumer-in-0.consumer.configuration.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.productsConsumer-in-0.consumer.configuration.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

java code, simple configuration class for only printing

```
@Configuration
@Lazy(false)
public class MessageProcessing implements IMessageProcessing {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> ordersConsumer() {
        return input -> {
            System.out.println(input);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> productsConsumer() {
        return input -> {
            System.out.println(input);
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to set auto.offset.reset=earliest?

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the response. yes, I tried, but nothing happened. it looks like I dont have a connection. When I tried on a fresh project all worked, but in my project(have a lot of dependencies) it doesnt work. But with simple spring kafka (KafkaListener) it works perfectly, so I guess maybe it is some conflicts, but I am not sure

Comment: Did you debug with `kafka-consumer-groups` to check the committed offsets for your consumer group?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it seems spring clod kafka doesnt work, like didnt start, or cant connect. For example: on fresh project, I have consumer logs (about configuring, subscription, etc) on the start server, but in my project, I didnt have any of these logs ( properties, versions and code the same)
if I use spring kafka, without spring cloud, it works perfectly ) I use spring 6, boot 3. maybe some other package blocks access for spring cloud, but I cant find conflicts

Comment: @OneCricketeer also I tried with `kafka-consumer-groups` with `--describe`, when I tried from my project, it didnt return any result, only `Error: Consumer group 'my-group' does not exist`
but in the fresh project, it returned detailed information

Comment: @OneCricketeer if we click to propertie `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092` it direct us to class `KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties`to setter `setBrokers` and in debug mode it didnt  stop here, so class didnt initialize

Comment: I don't use Spring, so cannot answer that, but based on the frequency of other questions posted here, I think it works fine, and should correctly create a consumer group, but only when offsets get acknowledged and committed. Otherwise, the code provided isn't anything that seems to need more than spring-kafka